# Registering a TagAction for all instances of HTML.UnknownTag

Tags: java, swing

I know that I can register a TagAction for a particular HTML.UnknownTag by doing something like this:

```
public static final HTML.Tag MY_TAG = new HTML.UnknownTag("mytag");
         .
         .
         .
registerTag(
    MY_TAG,
    new MyTagAction());
```

Is there a way I can register a TagAction for all instances of HTML.UnknownTag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://java-sl.com/custom_tag_html_kit.html

See the sources

```
class MyHTMLReader extends HTMLDocument.HTMLReader {
    public MyHTMLReader(int offset) {
        super(offset);
    }
    public void handleStartTag(HTML.Tag t, MutableAttributeSet a, int pos) {
        if (t.toString().equals("button")) {
            registerTag(t, new BlockAction());
        }
        super.handleStartTag(t, a, pos);
    }
}
```